# Could we install the syntaxhighter plugin for the GIS blog?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, blog

Using the current tools in the GIS blog results in loss off source code formatting, when switching from the HTML to the View tab.

As a workaround, I think we should try the syntaxhighlighter plugin for wordpress.

http://www.viper007bond.com/wordpress-plugins/syntaxhighlighter/

Comment: Kirk can you modify your post with the syntaxhighlighter then post it please. Thanks for everyone's patience.

Answer (score 7):

This has been installed, let me know if you have any trouble with it.

Comment: Thank you Rebecca, much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Looks a good tool - if the Stack Exchange Employees accept it and install it we can use it.

Detailed instructions for the install are here:

http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/manual/installation.html

(I am not sure if this would affect other overflow SE sites?)

Comment: +1 I think it would be important to have a tool like this. I found that I need good source code support in every second blog post.

Answer (score 2):

I've found storing code snippets as gists - https://gist.github.com/gists and then linking these in via JavaScript a good approach for including code in wordpress.

```
<script src="https://gist.github.com/784880.js"> </script>
```